# Open Source Push to Talk server / client

Tags: open-source, communication, voice

I'm looking for open source push to talk  PTT soluton like Zello for >1k users, with on premise server and mobile and desktop clients.
Appreciate for any advice ;)

Comment: did u get any solutions bro???

Comment: No. Finally we used Rocket.Chat instead.

Comment: does it support push to talk???

Comment: No. But it has voice and video  messages.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mumble.com/
Mumble is Open source and you can host you own server. It's available in many of the linux
pkg repos.

Turnkey ISO and VM available @ https://www.turnkeylinux.org/mumble

Client available for Linux, Windows, Android, MAC...